# DjangoCMS Install Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, django-cms, ubuntu-15.04

Trying to install django cms on a Ubuntu 15.04 machine.  I think I have most of the dependencies worked out, but every time I try to create a new project I get the following error message:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-g6zu6pce-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ci_5xa9n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-g6zu6pce-build
```

I am having no luck whatsoever in tracking this down.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:  setuptools, django, and djangocms-installer were all installed using both pip and pip3 inside of the virtualenv.  I was originally getting the dreaded Pillow errors, but I installed Pillow system-wide and that seems to have stopped.  Either that or I'm just not getting to that point yet.

There is one note that I should have included, but I wasn't sure if it was meaningful.  When I first start the virtualenv I get the following warning.  It's not an error, per se, in that it allows me to continue, but perhaps it is worth noting:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2 New python executable in env/bin/python2 Not overwriting existing python script env/bin/python (you must use env/bin/python2)
```

I start the env by using

```
source env/bin/activate
```

And it runs without issue.

Comment: Did you installed setuptools ?

Comment: How did you install it and how are you trying to create a new project?

Comment: I'll answer both of these with edits to the original question.